# How to redirect to frontpage from a controller

Tags: 8, redirection

Right now I'm doing this ugly thing to get the url of the my set frontpage (skipping validations and making sure it exists since I'm not sure if I'll even use this approach)

```
$url = $this->config('system.site')->get('page')['front'];
return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

This **works** but seems ugly, bloated and wrong.

Update:

As pointed out in the comments, this may be a matter of personal taste, therefore the question would be deemed subjective and it can be closed. It surely isn't a duplicate, I'm not asking **how to redirect** in general, it's a specific redirection, perhaps I could've worded it differently.

Comment: What's ugly about it? What would a beautiful version look like exactly? Where else do you want to get the data from if not config? How would you store it if not keyed by string? Without knowing what you consider to be the correct approach, this basically can't be answered. Alternatives may be listed, but how could we know if they meet your standards either?

Comment: If you don't see anything wrong with it, I guess it's a matter of personal taste then. I wasn't sure if accessing the configuration as such was reliable. To whomever downvoted my question, care to explain why?

Comment: not a duplicate, linked question is for a redirect to any url in a hook, this couldn't be more different, it is for a controller and a redirect to the frontpage, for which there is a route predefined in D8

Comment: I was deliberately trying to make that comment un-opinionated @JuanCortés - "ugly", "bloated" and "wrong" are all rather negatively charged words, which isn't really a problem, but without knowing what you would consider to be a positive DX around the same thing, it's difficult to respond with anything _other_ than an opinion. If it's based on something tangible (e.g it's a lot of typing, there's unchecked function return array dereferencing going on, etc), that would give answerers something more to get their teeth into

Comment: You're right, I approached this question putting my own answer down from the get go, thanks for taking the time to discuss it. @Clive It's absurd that a question can be marked as an exact duplicate of another one by 5 different mods, that have *clearly* not read my question. Working as automatons and only reading the titles ensure false positives, this is one of those cases.

Comment: Yeah kinda broke down there. Won't help much but closing is usually pretty accurate around here, not sure why this one went quite so wrong especially considering your edit. Try not to take it too personally, I'm positive it wasn't intended that way; I've opened it back up agaiin

Comment: As side note, notice that none of the users who voted to close the question were moderators. Moderators are only those users with a diamond close to their username.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes I see that now, even though I'm completely new in this particular site I used to be pretty active in **so** and I had the feeling that once a question gets a vote to be closed it's easier for others to  just go with the flow and say it's also closable without paying much attention to it.  I really appreciate the work mods put into these sites, thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the route `<front>` and when you are in a controller use the injected method redirect():

```
return $this->redirect('<front>');
```

Comment: This is what I was after, I was sure I had seen something like it before. It even works from a form submission with `$form_state->setRedirect('<front>')`. Cheers

Comment: In case someone finds some weird behavior when for example setting cookies before the redirect, you should actually use return $this->redirect('<front>')->send();

Hope it saves someone the time I spent hitting my head against the table for this.

Comment: @Marc, don't send a response in Drupal. Even if it works now in dev this will cause unpredictable behavior in production.